# Need an idea to write bash deployment upgrade script

Tags: bash

I want to write a single script in bash for deployment/Patching with almost minimum user interaction:-

Basically there would be following modules/Cases:-

1.) Fresh install (deploy a.war, b.war, c.war and create DB for respective war)

## Patching (Could be of various Permutations and combinations:---)

Like

2.) only update a.war

3.) only update b.war

4.) only update c.war

5.) only update db for a.war

6.) only update db for b.war

7.) only update db for c.war

8.) update a.war and and its db

9.) update b.war and its db

10.) update c.war and its db

and other combinations......

Basically I am thinking currently to source a conf file in which i will read a vairable like

Build:- 000000  ->Will take fresh install

100000--> only update a.war

010000--> only update b.war

001000--> only update c.war

100100--> update a.war and its db
.

.

and based on case. I get from conf file I could call respective functions.

The disadvantage of this approach is I Would have to crete case value for various combinations .

Is this the only way for my scenario or I can try something else ?

Please suggest:---

Answer (score 0):

The `cut` command can read a specific character from a line:

E.g.

```
conf=001000
update_a=$(echo $conf | cut -b1)
update_b=$(echo $conf | cut -b2)
update_c=$(echo $conf | cut -b3)
```

However, if you're reading this stuff from a conf file you might like to write that file in shell syntax and then just `source` it:

myconfig.txt:

```
update_a=false
update_b=false
update_c=true
```

script.sh:

```
. myconfig.txt

if $update_a; then
   ....
fi
if $update_b; then
   ....
fi
if .....
```

Alternatively, you could write the config in plain words and just use case:

myconfig.txt:

```
update_c update_f do_whatever
```

script.sh:

```
config=`read myconfig.txt`

case "$config" in
*update_a* )
  ....
  ;;
*update_b* )
  ....
```